# How to use in-place QComboBox with a QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, uitableview, combobox, window

I'm working with a `QTableView` and I want add a `QComboBox` in the 3rd column of every cell. There will be thousands of cells so I have opted for an in place editor solution. I want the combo box to be displayed when the user enters a cell by clicking or when the users uses the arrow key to select a cell in the 3rd column.

```
void FixtureCalibrationPage::on_View_clicked(const QModelIndex & index)
{
    if(!index.isValid()) return;
    if(index.column() != 3) return;
    if(selected_table_row == index.row()) return;
    if(selected_table_row != -1) { //clean up
        ui.view->setIndexWidget(index, NULL);
    }
    selected_table_row = index.row();
    ui.view->setIndexWidget(index, &m_combo_box_selection); //set the 
}
```

Click does not cover the case of using a the arrow keys. Is my only option to manually check if the users pressed the Arrow key or does another solution already exists?

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Answer (score 1):

That's what delegates are for. Create a delegate object for the view and set it on the 3rd column by using `setItemDelegateForColumn`. Note that delegates *must not be shared by multiple views*. Each view needs its own delegate. It makes sense for the delegate to be a child of the view.

In your delegate, you will create the combo box in the implementation of `createEditor` method. You of course need to implement `setEditorData`, `setModelData`, etc.

Comment: I originally started by looking at delegates but the delegate I created was not displaying. The examples I used did not say anything about `setItemDelegateForColumn`. Do you know any resources with examples of this?

Comment: @andre As is usually the case, please create a minimal, single-file example. Look at my other answers to see how single-file Qt applications look - almost every answer where I give significant amount of code, is a self-contained, single-file, compilable and tested.

Comment: @andre The `setItemDelegateForColumn` is nothing special. It's just one of the four methods that you can use to set a delegate on a view. You probably didn't set the delegate on the model. It's hard to tell without looking at the code. I'm sick and tired of dealing with being told "I've tried this" and then facing a refusal to share the code. I don't want a wall of code. Give a short example of how it didn't work. **Minimal** is a key word. If you do it right, it should barely need to scroll in your question.

Comment: @andre Qt includes at least four delegate examples. Qt Creator -> Welcome pane -> Examples -> type *delegate* in the search bar, click Enter. How hard can it be?

Comment: Long story short my old way works when I use `setItemDelegateForColumn` instead of `setItemDelegate` it works. I'll have to look into why it was not working before once I investigate tomorrow.